# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

My query below runs fine without the MAX(colName) lines. The original query selects about 100 columns, but now the MAX(colName) columns need to be added. Obviously when I add them, MS SQL complains with the error:

`"Column 'applicationId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"`

Is there any way to add these computed value columns without having to change the other 100 columns in the select?? The example below is simplified but the original query is a lot bigger and more complex.

```
                SELECT 
                     g.applicationId,
                     -- (another 100 or so columns just like above)
                    -- max(g.AScore) as AScore,
                    -- max(g.APercentile) as APercentile
                FROM application a
                LEFT JOIN GREScores g ON a.applicationId = g.applicationId
                WHERE g.applicationID = 1
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Looks like the subquery approach mentioned by @OVais did the trick. If you believe this is not a good approach, please tell me why:

```
                SELECT 
                     g.applicationId,
                     -- (another 100 or so columns just like above)
                    (SELECT MAX(AScore) FROM GREScores WHERE GREScores.applicationId = a.applicationId) AS tAScore
                    -- max(g.APercentile) as APercentile
                FROM application a
                LEFT JOIN GREScores g ON a.applicationId = g.applicationId
                WHERE g.applicationID = 1
```

Comment: How many rows are you expecting in the output? All that match the condition `g.applicationID = 1` or just one aggregated row for that condition?

Comment: @Cheeky: Are `AScore` and `APercentile` fields of table `GREScores` or are they computed columns?

Comment: @Cheeky: And do you want `MAX(AScore)` and `MAX(APercentile)` over all the table? If yes, @EricZ's answer should work for you.

Comment: @ypercube: Sorry, post updated. I left out the original table in simplifying the query.

Comment: @Cheeky: You still haven't answered on what exactly you want, the MAX over all table or the aggregate MAX over the groups.

Comment: And (irrelevant to the question): The `LEFT JOIN` is cancelled by the `WHERE g.applicationID = 1` condition. An `INNER JOIN` will give same results here.

Comment: @ypercube: GREScores contains multiple score records per application. Therefore for each application, I want the maximum / highest AScore and APercentile per application. So I would like to see something like {applicationId:1, AScore:445, APercentile:95}. Hope that clears up any confusion I caused.

Comment: @Cheeky: Then you need GROUP BY. See @gbn's answer (first part).

Comment: @Cheeky: Then @gbn's solution (the query in the 'Edit' part) will do just as well, unless you are on SQL Server 2000 or earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subquery instead of using aggregate function..
select col1,col2,(select Sum(col3) from table_name) as Sum from table_name

Comment: Thanks @Ovais. Your route was the way I decided to go as seen in the update I made above.

Answer (score 8):

The GROUP BY is there to ensure the query is semantically correct. What if you have 14 different values for column56: what should SQL Server *guess* that you want 14 rows in the output or collapse to MAX?

The SQL standard requires the GROUP BY to be populated (of mainstream RDBMS, only MySQL doesn't and makes a guess to resolved the ambiguity).

Now, there are ways around this:

- copy/paste from SELECT list to GROUP BY
- drag from the table column node which generates a CSV list in the query editor

Edit:

My answer above is for "MAX per grouping of the 100 columns".

If you want "All rows, with a single MAX for all rows" then you can use windowing

```
        SELECT 
             g.applicationId,
             -- (another 100 or so columns just like above)
            max(g.AScore) OVER () as AScore,
            max(g.APercentile) OVER () as APercentile
        FROM GREScores g
        WHERE g.applicationID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Max` is an aggregate function

you need to add a `GROUP BY` for all the other columns at the end...

Comment: actually cheeky wants to avoid use of groupy by with 100 columns which are othern than the column used with Max() function....

Comment: Exactly what Ovais said. Which is why I specifically mentioned the other 100 columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *
 FROM GREScores g
 WHERE g.applicationID = 1
)
SELECT 
     g.applicationId,
     -- (another 100 or so columns just like above)
    AScore =(select  max(g2.AScore) FROM cte g2) ,
    APercentile =(select  max(g2.APercentile) FROM cte g2)
FROM cte g
```

Comment: And will generate 3 scans on the table, rather than 1, so won't scale

Comment: A windowed aggregate might be a better choice. It would reflect just the data selected, not the entire table, which, in my opinion, would be more logical. Still, we are yet to learn what the actual output should be, of course.

Comment: @gbn: Would it be better to have `AScore = (SELECT MAX(AScore) FROM GREScores) WHERE applicationID = 1` instead?

Comment: @ypercube: Same result, the CTE is just a macro here. The subquery may be evaluated once per row too, even if it isn't, it may not give correct results because of a missing GROUP BY: how may rows does OP want? All rows from GREScores or aggregated?

Comment: I'm downvoting because this isn't the same query: there is no aggregate collapsing all rows in GREScores to the groups defined by the 100 columns. There will be a different MAX for each group: this gives one MAX for all rows with 200% more table scans

Comment: @gnd, you are right. I may misunderstood @cheeky's question. I thought he want same max value on whole query.

Answer (score 0):

Corelated subquery is one of methods to do this