# Efficiently Include Column not in Group By of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Given

**Table A**

```
Id   INTEGER
Name VARCHAR(50)
```

**Table B**

```
Id   INTEGER
FkId INTEGER  ; Foreign key to Table A
```

I wish to count the occurrances of each `FkId` value:

```
SELECT FkId, COUNT(FkId) 
FROM B 
GROUP BY FkId
```

Now I simply want to also output the Name from `Table A`.

This will not work:

```
SELECT FkId, COUNT(FkId), a.Name
FROM B b
INNER JOIN A a ON a.Id=b.FkId
GROUP BY FkId
```

because `a.Name` is not contained in the `GROUP BY` clause (produces `is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause` error).

The point is to move from output like this

```
FkId  Count
1      42
2      25
```

to output like this

```
FkId  Count  Name
1      42     Ronald
2      22     John
```

There are quite a few matches on SO for that error message, but some e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456944/141172 have comments like "will generate 3 scans on the table, rather than 1, so won't scale".

How can I *efficiently* include a field from the joined `Table B` (which has a 1:1 relationship to `FkId`) in the query output?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired results? I'm having a hard time understanding if there can be more than one unique name per FkId.

Comment: There would be only one unique name per FkId.  The point is just to show the name alongside the FkId so the user looking at the result doesn't see "Person 1 showed up 42 times" but rather sees "Person 1, whose name is Ronald, showed up 42 times".

Comment: So why not just add Name to the group by?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
   ;WITH GroupedData AS
   (
       SELECT FkId, COUNT(FkId) As FkCount
       FROM B 
       GROUP BY FkId
   ) 
   SELECT gd.*, a.Name
   FROM GroupedData gd
   INNER JOIN dbo.A ON gd.FkId = A.FkId
```

Create a CTE (Common Table Expression) to handle the grouping/counting on your `Table B`, and then join that result (one row per `FkId`) to `Table A` and grab some more columns from `Table A` into your final result set.

Comment: That's pretty much the same as the solution I linked to, which had the comment `And will generate 3 scans on the table, rather than 1, so won't scale`.  Will this solution really do 3 table scans as that commentor suggests?

Comment: @EricJ.: Well - copy the query, run it in your SQL Server Mgmt Studio and have "Actual Execution Plan" turned on, and you will see that **NO** it will **NOT** do three table scans ..... the comment in the answer you linked to is correct because the query there does **two extra** `(SELECT ....)` subqueries - **those** will add one table scan each (**NOT** the CTE used for the grouping!)

Comment: +1 for using actual execution plan to diagnose performance.  :-)

Comment: too often it's easy to "look" at a query instead of actually looking a the execution plan.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 requires a name for COUNT(FkId).  Edited accordingly.

Comment: Why is there a semicolon before `WITH`?

Comment: @kodkod: because there **must be** a semicolon (or a `GO`) before the `WITH` statement. It really should be part of the *previous statement* - but since I cannot always control that, I use a `;WITH` approach to make sure the `WITH` gets the semicolon it needs

Comment: Is this method better(performance wise or...) than the other answer provided by @MikeShepard below? (i think why this gets so higher up votes? may be that other one can not be used in all cases?)

Comment: @S.Serpooshan: performance can depends on **sooooo many** factors - just **try it for yourself!**

Comment: @marc_s i mean when just adding a field to our `group by` do the trick, why should we wrote such a long query you provided here and it is interesting that it gets more up votes?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try adding the field to the group by?

```
SELECT FkId, COUNT(FkId), a.Name
FROM B b
INNER JOIN A a ON a.Id=b.FkId
GROUP BY FkId,a.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t3.Name, t3.FkId, t3.countedFkId from (a t1 
  join (select t2.FkId, count(FkId) as countedFkId from b t2 group by t2.FkId) 
  on t1.Id = t2.FkId) t3;
```

Comment: Please use `{}` not ` to highlight code blocks. And don't be afraid of carriage returns. Also I don't think this query parses (the derived table needs an alias).

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advise. Still new to the syntax here :) And I guess you're right about needing an alias for the derived table.