# Select column not included in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL Server script:

```
SELECT
    cicmpy.cmp_name as Naam
    ,c2.cmp_name as Arts
    ,cicmpy.textfield1 as Voornaam
    ,items.UserField_02 as Label
    ,absences.HID
FROM
    Absences
INNER JOIN 
    cicmpy ON Absences.CustomerID = cicmpy.cmp_wwn
INNER JOIN 
    cicmpy as c2 ON Absences.FreeGuidField_01 = c2.cmp_wwn
INNER JOIN 
    Items ON absences.ItemCode = items.ItemCode
WHERE 
    Absences.Type = 86
```

I need all the columns I have in the `SELECT` statement but only the unique ones. As it is, the column `HID` is an unique column, so grouping on it returns all the rows. I tried to achieve my goal with a [CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369353/efficiently-include-column-not-in-group-by-of-sql-query) but didn't succeed. How can I get all the unique records based on the columns except the `HID` column?

Comment: You just want distinct of those columns?

Comment: Why do you want to also return HID? Which HID do you want to return? There can be multiple HID's in one group.

Comment: Can you give us a little sample data and your desired result?  It sounds like you may just need to use `select distinct...`.

Comment: please tell us what is your current output like and what you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 cicmpy.cmp_name as Naam
,c2.cmp_name as Arts
  ,cicmpy.textfield1 as Voornaam
  ,items.UserField_02 as Label
FROM Absences
  INNER JOIN cicmpy
    ON Absences.CustomerID = cicmpy.cmp_wwn
inner join cicmpy as c2
   on Absences.FreeGuidField_01 = c2.cmp_wwn
inner join Items
   on absences.ItemCode = items.ItemCode
where Absences.Type = 86
```

OR

if you are wanting some HID, you will need to choose what kind of aggregation you will use (`MIN` or `MAX`)

```
SELECT 
   cicmpy.cmp_name as Naam
  ,c2.cmp_name as Arts
  ,cicmpy.textfield1 as Voornaam
  ,items.UserField_02 as Label
  , MAX(Absences.HID) as MAX_HID
  , MIN(Absences.HID) as MIN_HID
FROM Absences
  INNER JOIN cicmpy
    ON Absences.CustomerID = cicmpy.cmp_wwn
inner join cicmpy as c2
   on Absences.FreeGuidField_01 = c2.cmp_wwn
inner join Items
   on absences.ItemCode = items.ItemCode
where Absences.Type = 86
GROUP BY 
   cicmpy.cmp_name
  ,c2.cmp_name
  ,cicmpy.textfield1
  ,items.UserField_02
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT

 cicmpy.cmp_name as Naam
,c2.cmp_name as Arts
  ,cicmpy.textfield1 as Voornaam
  ,items.UserField_02 as Label
  ,absences.HID
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cicmpy.cmp_name, c2.cmp_name, cicmpy.textfield1, items.UserField_02 ORDER BY absences.HID DESC) AS rn
FROM
  Absences
  INNER JOIN cicmpy
    ON Absences.CustomerID = cicmpy.cmp_wwn
inner join cicmpy as c2
on Absences.FreeGuidField_01 = c2.cmp_wwn
inner join Items
on absences.ItemCode = items.ItemCode
where Absences.Type = 86   
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```