# Include Column in SELECT not in Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Order and Order_Item.

**Order** has columns:
1) Order_Id Integer
2) Order_Time Date

**Order_Item** has columns:
1) Order_Item_Id Integer
2) Order_Id Integer(FK)
3) Order_Quantity Integer
4) Product_Id (FK) // from Product table(Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price)

I want to write a query like this:

> SELECT Product_Id , COUNT(Product_Id)*Order_Quantity
>  FROM
>   Order_Item, Order 
>  WHERE Order.Date BETWEEN '31-dec-2015' and
>   '5-jan-2016'
>  AND Order_Item.Order_Id =Order.Order_Id
>  GROUP
>   BY OrderItem.Product_Id ;

Results should look like:

Product_Id   Number_of_orders_from_customers
1                             23
2                             45

I found a lot of solutions(like this [Efficiently Include Column not in Group By of SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369353/efficiently-include-column-not-in-group-by-of-sql-query)) but the problem is that I Order_Quantity from the query with GROUP BY.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ?

```
SELECT Product_Id , COUNT(*) AS Number_of_orders_from_customers
FROM Order_Item, Order 
WHERE Order.Date BETWEEN '31-dec-2015' and '5-jan-2016'
AND Order_Item.Order_Id =Order.Order_Id
GROUP BY OrderItem.Product_Id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `sum`, as well as proper join syntax, table aliases, and standard date formats:

```
SELECT oi.Product_Id , SUM(oi.Order_Quantity)
FROM Order_Item oi JOIN
     `Order` o
     ON oi.Order_Id = o.Order_Id
WHERE o.OrderTime BETWEEN '2015-12-31' and '2015-01-05'
GROUP BY oi.Product_Id ;
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I need. Thank you!