# GROUP BY day of Datetime SQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a Sales report by PHP. The transaction date and time is on column `LastUpdateTime` with format: `m-d-Y H:i:s`. Now I wanna make report for 1 week, so I need the sum of TotalAmount of all transaction in 1 day, so I use group by `DAY` of `LastUpdateTime`. Here is my code but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
include 'report/go.php'; //DB connect
                                    $today =time();
                                    $from_time = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('last Monday'));
                                    $to_time = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('next Monday - 1 MIN'));
    $sql = "SELECT 
            SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalPerDay , LastUpdateTime, DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)
            FROM Tickets
            WHERE LastUpdateTime BETWEEN '$from_time' and '$to_time'
            GROUP BY DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)
            ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if( $stmt === false) 
            {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
            {
                $money = $row['TotalPerDay'];
                $date = date_format($row['LastUpdateTime'], "d-m-Y");
                echo $money." - ".$date."<br>";
            }
?>
```

Error returned:

> Column 'Tickets.LastUpdateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Please help :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: Put `LastUpdateTime` in the `Group By`?

Comment: It either has to be in a aggregate function e.g. `SUM / count / min / max` or in the `group by`

Comment: I just wanna Group By the DATE of the LastUpdateTime. because I'm looking for total revenue everyday.

Comment: How should I put it in the `group by` if I just wanna them to sum the revenue by days?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to include the `LastUpdateTime` in the `SELECT` list because multiple times will map to the same day.  So I think you should remove it.

Comment: Please tag dbms product used. (You have some non-ANSI SQL constructions there...)

Answer (score 3):

So you are using `lastUpdateTime` and `DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)` in select query, which are different. So for more than 1 `lastUpdateTime`, you can have same `DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)`. So if you group by `DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)`, then your Database would not know which `lastUpdateTime` should it return with it.

So either use `max(lastUpdateTime)` or any other aggregate function in select query.

```
SELECT 
        SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalPerDay 
        ,max(LastUpdateTime)
        ,DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)
        FROM Tickets
        WHERE LastUpdateTime BETWEEN '$from_time' and '$to_time'
        GROUP BY DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime),
        LastUpdateTime
```

Or add `lastUpdateTime` to group by clause, but it would not give you expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Either you use ..

```
SELECT      SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalPerDay , DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)
FROM        Tickets
WHERE       LastUpdateTime BETWEEN '$from_time' and '$to_time'
GROUP BY    DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime)
```

OR

```
SELECT      SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalPerDay , DATEPART(dd,LastUpdateTime), LastUpdateTime
FROM        Tickets
WHERE       LastUpdateTime BETWEEN '$from_time' and '$to_time'
GROUP BY    LastUpdateTime
```

> Because you can't select a column/computed result in group by select
>   statement if it is not part of group by clause

If you want your query to execute then below link might help you

[Efficiently Include Column not in Group By of SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369353/efficiently-include-column-not-in-group-by-of-sql-query)

[Select a Column in SQL not in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991079/select-a-column-in-sql-not-in-group-by)

Comment: Thanks, but both your solutions didn't work. Another error appears: `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`

Comment: So it seems that `LastUpdateTime` column datatype is varchar.. right??

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I figured out my solution

`SELECT 
            SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalPerDay , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LastUpdateTime,103) AS TicketDateTime
            FROM Tickets
            WHERE LastUpdateTime BETWEEN '$from_time' and '$to_time'
            GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),LastUpdateTime,103)`

I used `CONVERT` instead of `DATEPART`, then I still have the Sales date, and still able to `GROUP BY` the `TotalAmount`

Thanks everyone so much